# How to get Django ImageField name

Tags: python, django

How to get ImageField name In django.

settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'myApp\media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
DEFAULT_LOGO = MEDIA_ROOT + '\logo.jpg'
```

I have following model:

```
class Firm(models.Model):
"""
    Firm model class
"""
.....
logo = models.ImageField(upload_to=MEDIA_ROOT, default=DEFAULT_LOGO)


def firm_logo(self):
    return '<img src="/media/%s" width="100" height="100" />' % self.logo.name
firm_logo.allow_tags = True
```

What i want is an Image name which is `logo.jpg`. So that i can use it in URL. I have tried  `self.logo.name, self.logo` both are returning image directory path.

`c:\Users\...\myApp\media\logo.jpg`

But i want `logo.jpg`

Comment: May be `self.logo.name` is not working because i have used `default=DEFAULT_LOGO` and it is saved as a image name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`FileField.url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.url) (`ImageField` is a subclass of the `FieldField`):

```
return '<img src="%s" width="100" height="100" />' % self.logo.url
```

Comment: This answers the question, but I think the `img` tag should go in templates, and not in views.

Comment: @cor, I think the `firm_logo` is for admin listing page. I guessed so because of `firm_logo.allow_tags = True`.

Comment: `display_image` is for admin interface only not for view.

Comment: @user2217267, Do you mean `firm_logo`?

Comment: Ok, sorry my ignorance

Comment: Thanks guys....It was all my mistake......because i used `DEFAULT_LOGO` as a full path ...everything was messedup. when i changed it to `DEFAULT_LOGO = 'logo.jpg' self.logo.url` worked perfectly